# How to 'destroy' previous chart (canvas) after new one is shown | Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, charts

I have a code that update the data of an Graphic after a drop down is selected. However when I select an option it looks like the new Graphic and the old Graphic stays on the same canvas at the same time.

here's my code:

```
funcao(){

  this.graphicService.getDatas().subscribe(datas => {
        this.datas = datas; //Gets the data from the API and put on local datas variable

        if(this.data[0].dimension == "Tech")
        {
          this.counter=0;
        }
        else if(this.data[0].dimension == "Bus"){
          this.counter=1;
        }
              this.barChartData = { //Bar graphic data
                  labels: ["Entry", "Foundation"],
                  datasets: [{
                      label: this.datas[this.counter].subdimensions[0].name,
                      backgroundColor: 'rgba(37, 230, 131,0.7)'
                      data: [
                          this.datas[this.counter].subdimensions[0].entry,
                          this.datas[this.counter].subdimensions[0].foundation
                      ]
                  }]

              };

              this.canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
              this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

              let myChart = new Chart(this.ctx, { // Bar graphic configs
                     type: 'bar',
                     data: this.barChartData,
                     options: {
                         scales: {
                            yAxes: [{
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: true
                                }
                            }]
                          }
                     }
                 });
      });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="data[0].dimension" (change)="funcao()" class="form-control">
  <option *ngFor="let data of datas" [value]="data.dimension">{{ data.dimension }}</option>
</select>

  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

What I want to do is the old graphic disappears and only the new one stay on screen.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seems like you are using the ChartJS library. In that case, you can use the [**`destroy()`**](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#destroy) method to destroy any previous instance of chart.

**ꜰɪʀꜱᴛ**

add a property *(in which the chart instance gonna be stored)* in your chart component class :

```
public myChart: Chart
```

**ꜱᴇᴄᴏɴᴅ**

check and destroy the chart instance *(if any)* before creating a new one :

```
...
if (this.myChart) this.myChart.destroy(); //destroy prev chart instance
this.myChart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
         type: 'bar',
         data: this.barChartData,
         ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this has already been solved, but I was having the same problem and this solutions didn't work, probably because I am using recent versions.

In case someone is reading this thread and is in the same situation as me, this is what worked in my case: manually removing the canvas from the DOM in the ngOnDestroy() hook.

```
  ngOnDestroy(){
    ( < HTMLCanvasElement > document.getElementById('myChartCanvas')).remove();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The canvas api defines a **clearRect** method.

You can clear the canvas before creating a new chart.

```
this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 100,100);
```

You read the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect).

Comment: Nice to know, but where should I put that code? I tried to use it and now both new and old graphic are blank.

Comment: @Gustavo I added more to the answer.

Comment: Added it, but still the same issue as before (both new an old show at the same time)

Comment: the only other explanation would be that you actually have multiple charts generated for the same canvas at once. are you sure the chart library doesn't just update the drawing whenever `this.barChartData` is changed?

Answer (score 1):

try [`destroy()`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#destroy) method.

Keep accessible reference to your chart instance (`this.myChart` in my example):

```
this.myChart = new Chart(this.ctx, { // Bar graphic configs
  type: 'bar',
  data: this.barChartData,
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

then, when you need to destroy it, call:

```
// Destroys a specific chart instance
this.myChart.destroy();
```

here is `destroy()` function's code (copied from [CDN](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js)):

```
destroy : function(){
  this.clear();
  unbindEvents(this, this.events);
  var canvas = this.chart.canvas;

  // Reset canvas height/width attributes starts a fresh with the canvas context
  canvas.width = this.chart.width;
  canvas.height = this.chart.height;

  // < IE9 doesn't support removeProperty
  if (canvas.style.removeProperty) {
    canvas.style.removeProperty('width');
    canvas.style.removeProperty('height');
  } else {
    canvas.style.removeAttribute('width');
    canvas.style.removeAttribute('height');
  }

  delete Chart.instances[this.id];
}
```

and `clear()` function:

```
clear = helpers.clear = function(chart){
  chart.ctx.clearRect(0,0,chart.width,chart.height);
}
```

so, `destroy()` function take care of both ChartJS and canvas APIs, and, as [stated on the official site](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#destroy):

> This must be called before the canvas is reused for a new chart

Comment: It looks like the data are always on the same canvas like @toskv mentioned above. So no matter when I destroy it, when the new one comes in there will be the old data on the same canvas, I think.

Comment: `destroy()` function will take care of all needed actions on both CHartJS and canvas APIs. See my update on the answer